# Django admin messages show's in my view

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm using django messages framework to show user errors and help messages, but if i don't add message to "messages" object, they still contains messages from django admin "My last actions".
Only answer i found is to add empty message, but this is bad solution.
So, how to use message framework but don't show admin messages?

Comment: Why does that matter? As an admin, you'll see your own admin actions; non-admins wouldn't have any, so they wouldn't see them.

Comment: All users see this messages, not only admins.

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your installation. The messages framework is user-specific.

Comment: Theoritically, if the message is displayed at the wrong moment, it's because you forgot to display it when it was generated. If a message is added to the "messages" module but it not displayed (because the request is not transmitted to the template, or the template has no message block) then it will remain in the messages module and be displayed later. Does your admin action returns to a custom template ? It there a messages block in that template ?

Comment: It returns to default admin template.